# Why are the sockets constants(like SOCK_STREAM or SOCK_RAW) not explained in the documentation of python sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

No information are given on what these constants means, they only say they are the kind of the socket, but then for each i have to google the meaning somewhere else. Is there a guide somewhere where i can find more information on them?

I tried to look for more information on the python socket documentation but the explanations are completely missing

Comment: Python sockets are basically c sockets, with some things changed around. The place you want to look is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket

Comment: I agree this is an unfortunate state of affairs. The socket module documentation states "This module provides *access* to the BSD socket interface" and "Some behavior may be platform dependent" and "The Python interface is a straightforward transliteration of the Unix system call and library interface for sockets". The hint here is that you need to consult your platform documentation, e.g. `man socket` on a Unix system.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk In most cases, all platforms will share the same functions. Winsock is slightly different, but for basic stuff such as socket types of SOCK_STREAM and SOCK_RAW it will always be the same. P.S. Glad a president is here helping the good people of stackoverflow out.